# How to make a query in Firebase similar to a SQL query?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, firebase

I'm trying to develop an application for Android using Java. I am using the NoSQL Firebase database. However, it is very different from what I have learned so far, so I would like you to help me do something like this:

```
SELECT "name" FROM users WHERE email = "user@gmail.com"
```

using Firebase syntax. Could you help me?

Comment: Have a look at this official Video series: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the world of NoSQL databases, a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT "name" FROM users WHERE email = "user@gmail.com"
```

Can be written in two ways. If you are using [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)
, the query should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo("user@gmail.com");
```

And if you are using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), the query should look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
Query query = usersRef.whereEqualTo("email", "user@gmail.com");
```

**Edit:**

According to you comment, to get the name, please use the above lines along with the following lines of code:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185231/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-mamo-how-to-make-a-query-in-firebase-similar-to-a-s).